# How to extract PDF file to Pandas dataframe without header /title of table as dataframe considers it as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabula

Please help me in this as explained below I badly need help as I tried to solve this issue by myself and I wasted two days,All I want is the table ranging from page  10-23 its one single table and I donot want the header/title of table .
I am trying to read pdf file using Tabula ,All I want is the table from page # 10-23 without header.
Now the issue is I tried to extract the data in multiple ways and each way I face a different issue.
Why I tried multiple ways because each time the header /title of table created mess as dataframe considers it as only one single column .Please help

1-I tried to extract the table like below,It returns only one column along with rows and when I try to drop that header column and replace with first row it drops the last row along with it

```
                file_path="https://nycfuture.org/pdf/CUF_StateoftheChains_2019_7.pdf"
                df=tabula.read_pdf(file_path,encoding='utf-8',spreadsheet=True,pages='10-24')
                df.columns
```

This returns one column only which is header/title of table.

2-When I use pandas_options={header=none} in read_pdf function, It returns a list and when I try to convert list to Dataframe using Dataframe along with column name it returns an error showing below

```
file_path="https://nycfuture.org/pdf/CUF_StateoftheChains_2019_7.pdf"
             df=tabula.read_pdf(file_path,encoding='utf-8',pandas_options= 
            {'header':None},multiple_tables=True,spreadsheet=True,pages='10-24')

            ## Converting list to dataframe

           from pandas import DataFrame
            mydata= DataFrame(df,columns=['Retail Chain', 'Category', '2019','2018','2017', '2016', 
                     '2015', 'Brooklyn', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island'])


    It returns this error
    KeyError: "None of [Index(['Retail Chain', 'Category', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016', 
   '2015',\n       'Brooklyn', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island'],\n      
     dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

`
3-When I use to_csv option to store data and retrieve

```
df.to_csv('stores.csv')
brands_data=pd.read_csv("stores.csv")
 brands_data.head()
 It adds last column as row i.e Staten Island  to my dataframe
```

`
[Column added as row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFiyZ.png)

Comment: Have you attempted to manually clean the tables?

Comment: I tried to do that manually but didn't work.